# How to know if an atom or string is a valid identifier

Tags: erlang, elixir

Is there anything like Python's `str.isidentifier`:

```python
>>> "foo".isidentifier()
True
>>> "42".isidentifier()
False
```

Answer (score 4):

In Erlang, atoms are used to represent constant values.

```
Erlang/OTP 18 [erts-7.0] [source] [64-bit] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V7.0  (abort with ^G)
1> is_atom(sunday).
true
2> is_atom('sunday').
true
3> is_atom("sunday").
false
4>
```

And, there is no `string` type in erlang. `string` is just a list of integers.

```
8> B = [115,117,110,100,97,121].
"sunday"
9> is_list(B).
true
10>
```

Comment: That's not what I'm asking. I want to know if an atom is ok to be used as a function name. `foo` is ok, `'42'` is not.

Comment: Any atom, including `'42'`, can be a function name.

Comment: @RyanStewart: Good to know. I figured out how to define such a function in Elixir.

Comment: It's perhaps a bit nitpicky of me, but being a fundamental type I think it's more accurate to say "an atom IS a constant value", rather than "atoms are used to represent constant values".

Answer (score 4):

Any atom is a valid "identifier", in that it can be the name of a function, in both Erlang and Elixir.  However, since some atoms need to be quoted, you might need some tricks to actually define such a function.

In Erlang, quoting [the reference manual](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/data_types.html#id67942):

> An atom is to be enclosed in single quotes (') if it does not begin with a lower-case letter or if it contains other characters than alphanumeric characters, underscore (_), or @.

I couldn't find a similar description for Elixir, but I presume it's similar.

[This blog post](http://daniel-azuma.com/blog/2016/05/12/family-ties-3-its-all-in-a-name) addresses how to create such functions.  In short, in Erlang you just put the function name in single quotes, and you're done:

```
-module(fortytwo).

-export(['42'/1]).

'42'(X) ->
    {ok, X}.
```

This function can be called like this from the shell:

```
> fortytwo:'42'(a).
{ok,a}
```

In Elixir, you need to use the `unquote` macro to define the function:

```
defmodule Fortytwo do
  def unquote(:"42")(x) do
    {:ok, x}
  end
end
```

And there is no way to quote the function name in a normal function call, so you need to use `apply`:

```
> apply(Fortytwo, :"42", [:a])
{:ok, :a}
```

Comment: We can call it with `Fortytwo."42"(:a)`. I think what I want ask is actually "How do I know if I need to put `"` around a function name". Now I know there might not be a predefined function for this since it's only syntax related.

Comment: Ah, now I understand what you're asking! There's no predefined function as far as I know. One slightly hackish way to do this is to check whether the representation returned by `inspect` matches the atom itself: `(inspect :foo) == (":" <> Atom.to_string :foo)`